# Simple code of array gives me a Runtime error

Tags: c++, gcc

I can not understand why this code broke when I try to run it.
I use GCC compiler

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int arr[] = {0};

    for(int x=0; x<6; x++)
        arr[x] = x;
    for(int y=0; y<6; ++y)
        cout<< "arr[" << y <<"] = " << arr[y] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Have you read a basic C++ textbook on the subject of arrays?

Comment: You are declaring an array with only 1 element and then you are trying to write a value up to it's 6'th element. It will clearly not work

Comment: `arr` is automatically allocated and of size 0, it is not dynamic. In your example the size the array needs to be is known so you could just write `int arr[6];`. If you end up in a situation where you don't necessarily know the size of an array before runtime, you'd want to take a look at `std::vector`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`int arr[] = {0};` declares an array with exactly one element in it. Therefore, the only valid index into that array is `arr[0]`. Trying to index by any non-zero integer will result in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

you need

```
int arr[6];
```

to declare an array with 6 elements

Answer (score 0):

the error lies in the line:
    int a[]={0};
by this you have created an array that consists of only one element and later you are trying to access 6 elements. Replace the above line by:
    int a[6]={0};

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few ways to accomplish what you wish to do. Some are C style and some use C++ STL containers I've re-wrote you code in a 4 different ways to show the differences. There are c static sized arrays and c++ static sized classes (Size must be known at compile time), c dynamic sized arrays (these will be allocated on the heap, and c++ dynamic sized vectors. I recomend you do some reading on each but here are some basic examples.

```
#include <iostream>                                               
#include <vector>                                                 
#include <array>                                                  

using namespace std;                                              

int main() {                                                      

    // C style Static sized array                                 
    int arr_sty_1[6];                                             
    for(int x=0; x<6; x++)                                        
        arr_sty_1[x] = x;                                         
    for(int y=0; y<6; ++y)                                        
        cout<< "arr_sty_1[" << y <<"] = " << arr_sty_1[y] << endl;

    // C++ style Static sized array                               
    array<int, 6> arr_sty_2;                                      
    for(int x=0; x<6; x++)                                        
        arr_sty_2[x] = x;                                         
    for(int y=0; y<6; ++y)                                        
        cout<< "arr_sty_2[" << y <<"] = " << arr_sty_2[y] << endl;

    // C style dynamic sized array                                
    int* arr_sty_3 = new int[6];                                  
    for(int x=0; x<6; x++)                                        
        arr_sty_3[x] = x;                                         
    for(int y=0; y<6; ++y)                                        
        cout<< "arr_sty_3[" << y <<"] = " << arr_sty_3[y] << endl;

    // C++ style dynamic size vector (dynamic array ish)          
    vector<int> arr_sty_4;                                        
    for(int x=0; x<6; x++)                                        
        arr_sty_4.push_back(x);                                   
    for(int y=0; y<6; ++y)                                        
        cout<< "arr_sty_4[" << y <<"] = " << arr_sty_4[y] << endl;

    return 0;                                                     
}
```

Comment: Not sure what the downvote is about, but I have a minor niggle: C++ defines dynamic storage in such a way that a heap is not required. Heap is a common implementation, and likely all most programmers will ever see, but it is not the only implementation.